# gRPC java implementation v0.15 might lost data, was it fixed in v1? Backpressure?

Tags: grpc

When I was working with v0.15 of gRPC (java version) I've faced with issue that if client is slow, then some data might be simply lost. I.e. server emits lets say 5 mils records and client receives around 80 percents.

To handle this situation I had to implement local 'buffer' which seems to be an issue to me if I want to use gRPC for communication between microservices.

I wonder was this issue fixed in v1? I remember I've seen (googled) corresponding issue somethere in gRPC discussion, but cannot find it now.

I would assume it is somehow correlates with backpressure, do we have backpressure in gRPC out of the box? In my tests 1.0.2 blows with io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError:
Should I manually implement backpressure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sending a message does not imply the client has received it. The ClientCall and ServerCall APIs describe it as:

> No generic method for determining message receipt or providing acknowledgement is provided. Applications are expected to utilize normal payload messages for such signals, as a response naturally acknowledges its request.

I would agree your issue appears to be related to flow control/backpressure. You should cast the `StreamObserver` to a `ServerCallStreamObserver` and use `setOnReadyHandler()` and `isReady()` for controlling the memory usage. There's a [brief example in an issue comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2247#issuecomment-245949881).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Great note about onReadyHandler.

Comment: Trying to think further: I believe grpc uses tcp for communication which means client actually receives all data (in the other case we would see some kind of error). How can it be that client do not actually got all entries? What am I missing?

Comment: A write to TCP will complete before the other side has necessarily received it. Even if a write fails, the grpc-java API won't notify you during the write. Instead, it provides the error during the read/reply.